# Whenever I am trying to get username from Firebase it returns value but is not updated in String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Login Activity. Whenever I click to login button it successfully log me in on other hand I am also trying to get the username and Profile name from the database and it is success fully returning the value. Main problem is that when Firebase returns the value it is not getting updated into my string and showing it null whenever I am trying to retrieving it.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference ();
    String[] z= {""};
    EditText email,password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_login);
        email = findViewById (R.id.editUser);
        password = findViewById (R.id.editPass);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences ("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences ("isLoginned", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit ();
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferences2.edit ();
        Button signin = findViewById (R.id.signin);
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog (LoginActivity.this);

        dialog.setMessage ("Loging in.  Please wait");
        dialog.setTitle ("Login User");
        dialog.setCancelable (false);
        signin.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.show ();
                if(!email.getText ().toString ().equals (null) && !password.getText ().toString ().equals (null)){
                    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (email.getText ().toString (),password.getText ().toString ()).addOnCompleteListener (new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> () {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful ()){
                                int a = email.getText ().toString ().indexOf ("@");
                                SplashScreen.USERNAME = email.getText ().toString ().substring (0,a);
                                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child ("User").child (SplashScreen.USERNAME);
                                        DataSnapshot usernamee = snapshot.child ("Username");
                                        DataSnapshot name = snapshot.child ("Name");
                                        SplashScreen.IDNAME = String.valueOf (usernamee.getValue ());
                                        SplashScreen.NAME = String.valueOf (name.getValue ());
                                        editor.putString ("ussername", SplashScreen.IDNAME);
                                        editor.putString ("name", SplashScreen.NAME);
                                        editor.apply ();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                                        Toast.makeText (LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                                    }
                                });
                                dialog.dismiss ();
                                editor.putString ("Email",email.getText ().toString ());
                                editor.putString ("pass",password.getText ().toString ());
                                editor.putString ("Username",SplashScreen.USERNAME);
                                editor2.putString ("login","Yes");
                                editor.apply ();
                                editor2.apply ();
                                editor.commit ();
                                editor2.commit ();
                                Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, WallOfTheApp.class);
                                startActivity (intent);
                                finish ();
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener (new OnFailureListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            dialog.dismiss ();
                            Toast.makeText (LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Problem is in this context:

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child ("User").child (SplashScreen.USERNAME);
                                        DataSnapshot usernamee = snapshot.child ("Username");
                                        DataSnapshot name = snapshot.child ("Name");
                                        SplashScreen.IDNAME = String.valueOf (usernamee.getValue ());
                                        SplashScreen.NAME = String.valueOf (name.getValue ());
                                        editor.putString ("ussername", SplashScreen.IDNAME);
                                        editor.putString ("name", SplashScreen.NAME);
                                        editor.apply ();
```

It is my Firebase database:

```
{
  "User" : {
    "prathamkhurana43" : {
      "Mobile Number" : "1234567890",
      "Name" : "Pratham",
      "Username" : "prathamk22"
    }
  }
}
```

> Whenever I click the button first time it doens't get the value but on
>   second time clicking the login button gets me the value of the
>   username and profile name

Comment: Yaa whenever I use log inside the successfull statement, it shows the name in log but when I try to access that name using string, it returns null

Comment: check whether you typo creates the error editor.putString ("ussername", SplashScreen.IDNAME); try with editor.putString ("username", SplashScreen.IDNAME);

Comment: I tried it earlier but it doesn't helped me

Comment: please show the database

Comment: Firebase Database??

Comment: yes your database

Comment: I am updating my question along with database

Comment: Its updated and added onemore line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnasphot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String names=datas.child("Name").getValue().toString();
    String usernames=datas.child("Username").getValue().toString();
    editor.putString ("ussername",names);
    editor.putString ("name", usernames);
    editor.apply();
   }
```

This will give you the values `name` and `username` which can be used in shared preferences.

If you have this value `"prathamkhurana43"` you can do this also:

```
myRef.child("User").child("prathamkhurana43").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  //retrieve data without using the for loop
```

Comment: I can't use simply the email because user will enter the email and then app will retrieve the name and username fro firebase database

Comment: what email? @PrathamKhurana

Comment: if you mean this `prathamkhurana43` then just enter the value that the user enter inside child(//inside here) or just do the first way of iterating

Comment: It doesn't worked and I think problem is that when I click the login button, app gets the previous value of the string and after getting the value from database it updates the string variable and when i click another time on login button it works successfully. I want it to work on first time onle

Comment: then when you click login button dnt get the previous value and get the value from the database only so it can work in first time only

Comment: But it is not working in first time. It shows null value when I retrieve it

Comment: No actually I found the solution as I made a timer of 2 sec after which the value of name and username is used and It is working fine. Thank you